# Why the Weblogic console cannot be accessed by using port 80？

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

After installing patch 10.3.6.0.200114, Weblogic console could not log in, indicating "WebLogic Server has rejected this user name or password. Please try again. " However, the service can be accessed normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in this PSU which prevent web app like the admin console to authenticate users. Oracle published a patch to correct this issue : SU Patch [EIL8]: 10.3.6.0.200114WLSPSU Overlay: CANNOT LOGIN TO CONSOLE, BUT CAN LOGIN TO EM WITH THE SAME USER
Download it from MOS and patch your WebLogic server installation.